# email address obfuscate .net asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encode

Does anyone knows a .net alternative for obfuscation like [this way](http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html)?

as an output I'd like to be something like:

```
<A HREF="mailto:
&#121;&#111;&#117;&#114;&#110;&#097;&#109;&#101;&#064;&#100;&#111;&#109;&#097;&#105;&#110;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;">
&#121;&#111;&#117;&#114;&#110;&#097;&#109;&#101;&#064;&#100;&#111;&#109;&#097;&#105;&#110;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;
</A>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode a string like that using:

```
email =
  String.Concat(email.Select(c => "&#" + ((int)c).ToString() + ";").ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For some reason it removes the 'o'(zeros) from the string, do you have any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: @el.severo: Oh, you mean like `&#64;` instead of `&#064;`? They are not needed, but if you want a fixed number of digits, you can use `ToString("000")` instead of `ToString()` in the code.

Comment: Already tried with `ToString("000")` and `ToString("3D")` but the same approach. Thanks! :)

Comment: @el.severo: `ToString("3D")` doesn't work, but `ToString("000")` does work.